# Generate an image from a DIV content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a board game in HTML very similar than chess. This board game is based on a set of divs with background images set and from one game I wish I could take a picture of the whole board with the positions of the tabs to a particular item.

How could I do it with jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839216/create-an-image-of-a-div-in-javascript-gif-png

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with jquery.

Comment: Well, never mind. I can send the HTML code to PHP and save the image generated. Which code should i use?