# Print QR code in IE 8

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, qr-code

I have generated a QR code using jQuery plugin. The QR code is rendered in a **div** on my webpage. I tried to print the webpage but the qrcode is not printed in the paper.

My code for jQuery for QR code generation:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {  
    $('#add1').click(function () {
        $("#table1").remove();
        var string2 = document.getElementById("textinput").value;

        jQuery('#qrcodeTable').qrcode({
            render: "table",
            text: string2
        });
    });
});
```

In view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{  
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.encode, new { id = "textinput", style = display:none;" }
}     

<div id="qrcodeTable">         
</div>
```

EDIT :
[image: Taking Print from webpage]
[image: Print Preview image]

The qrcode doesnot gets printed from the webpage. Any suggestions.

Comment: obviously, they want it to print out.

Comment: Can you change the render to render an image? I'm *guessing* that the "table" render method creates a table with cells and the black cells have a background set. Some browsers won't print backgrounds by default. EDIT: Checked the example and it does use background colour. Remove the "render" option to render to canvas and see if that works. Otherwise you'll need to switch on printing backgrounds.

Comment: I can suggest you to generate image of that "#qrcodeTable". see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839216/create-an-image-of-a-div-in-javascript-gif-png

Comment: @BernhardHofmann , I tried using canvas.  Got a  Object doesn't support this property or method error in this line .var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); In jQuery plugin

Comment: @kk1076 If you're using IE and it's for a limited audience, you might be able to have the background printing enabled: Tools>Options>Advanced>Printing>Print background colors and images. Otherwise I fear you'll need a different QR code library; maybe http://d-project.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/misc/qrcode/js/