# How to create an image from a screenshot in a web app using Python / jQuery (or other option?)

Tags: javascript, python, image, flask

I am writing a web app in Python/Flask and in the HTML the users can create a special type of chart which is basically an image in a div that when the user clicks it overlays circle divs on top of it.

Right now users are just taking a screen shot of the generated chart but I am looking for an easier way to do this using either Python or Javascript/jQuery that knows how to make an image based on the contents in a specific div.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Why don't you use a charting library that uses canvas and you can save that canvas object to an image?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839216/create-an-image-of-a-div-in-javascript-gif-png